# Got "permission denied" when emulating sh under zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, bash

I just switched to `zsh` as my default Mac OS terminal shell. However, I found it won't automatically hit the `~/.profile` file. After researching on Google, it looks like it can be solved by adding the following command in `~/.zprofile` to emulate whatever in `~/.profile`:

```
emulate sh -c '~/.profile'
```

However, I got the follwoing error when terminal starting up:

> zsh:1: permission denied: /Users/XXX/.profile

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what do you need ~/.profile for? do you mean ~/.zshrc?

Comment: I put some environment variables like JAVA_HOME in ~/.profile before I switched to zsh. I'm trying to figure out a way to let zsh to "source" those environment variables when starting up. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile) is the article I found and was trying to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish your goal, you'd have to use:

```
emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'  # Note the `source`; alternatively, use `.`
```

Without the `source`, `~/.profile` would run in a *subshell*, which defeats your intent (`export`s wouldn't "stick"); **you have to *source* that other file**.
(The specific error you saw stems from an attempt to execute `~/.profile` *directly*, without its being marked as executable. Note that shell profiles normally needn't be executable, because their only purpose is to be (automatically) *read* by a shell. It's a moot point, however, given that *sourcing* from within a shell is needed.)

As for what `zsh` initialization file to put the command in:

- On macOS, if you've made **`zsh` your *default* shell**, then **`~/.zprofile` works**, as all shells you'll open in a terminal will be ***login* (`zsh`) shells**, which will read that file.
- Generally, though, **`~/.zshrc` is the better choice**, as that file gets sourced by *any* interactive `zsh` shell, whether it's a login shell or not. It's also **the file to use with the [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) framework**.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should be using `.zshrc`

Add this to `~/.zshrc`:

`EXPORT JAVA_HOME="whatever"`

And type `$ source ~/.zshrc` in your terminal window, or start a new shell instance.

Follow up:
[this article](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) lists the startup files loading order which clarifies the confusion.

Comment: I know this will work. But I prefer to put all the environment variables in one place at ~/.profile and just let zsh to source it when starting up. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there a reason why you need it to be in a single file? Or is this just for simplicity.

Comment: Just for simplicity. I think it might be hard for future maintenance if I have environment variables at 2 places. Any suggestion?

Comment: did some research, [Note that zsh seems to read ~/.profile as well, if ~/.zshrc is not present.](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/). So maybe try getting rid of `.zshrc` and/or `.zprofile` entirely?

Comment: this article clarifies the confusion! Since am using Oh-My-Zsh, I can't get rid of .zshrc. I will compromise to source the .profile file in .zshrc

Comment: ah, I use that too. glad this helped!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to source `~/.profile` - see my answer. The sentence "And type $ `source ~/.zshrc` in your terminal window, after starting zsh." is potentially confusing: Any `zsh` instance started _after_ `~/zshrc` has been created/updated will _automatically_ source that file (which is the whole point); `source ~/.zshrc` is only needed to make an _already-running_ shell pick up changes in `~/.zshrc` that were made _after_ that shell was started.